# ORDER BY before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a page showing a list of persons with whom you have been chatting to. Currently it's showing the persons you have been chatting to, and the OLDEST message. However, it should show the NEWEST message. This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM post
WHERE fk_user_to = '$userid'
GROUP BY fk_user_from
ORDER BY datotime DESC
```

and the table structure

```
post_id || fk_user_to || fk_user_from || message || datotime
```

Comment: I assume you tried ASC instead of DESC?

Comment: Yes i have, Stanislav.
And it's MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked out:

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY datotime DESC) as inv
    WHERE fk_user_to = '$userid'
    GROUP BY fk_user_from
    ORDER BY datotime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really work like that. You can never be sure what row GROUP BY selects, so putting an ORDER BY on it will have unpredictable output. Also you cannot put an order by BEFORE a GROUP BY.

Try this:

```
SELECT *,MAX(datotime) AS dt fk_user_from
FROM post
WHERE fk_user_to = '$userid'
GROUP BY fk_user_from
ORDER BY dt
```

Comment: That would not provide the newest `message` row value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution with plain SQL I think. If your database system allows subqueries, you got do a subquery like

```
SELECT fk_user_from AS id, MAX(dateotime) AS newest_timestamp FROM post WHERE fk_user_to = '$userid'
```

and then select from `post` again using the two fields as key.

In MySQL that could be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM post P1 
JOIN (
    SELECT fk_user_from, MAX(dateotime) AS newest_dateotime 
    FROM post 
    WHERE fk_user_to = '$userid'
    GROUP BY fk_user_from
) AS P2
ON  P1.fk_user_from=P2.fk_user_from
AND P1.datotime    =P2.newest_dateotime
WHERE P1.fk_user_to = '$userid'
```

Comment: I am getting an error using this.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE fk_user_to = '1' ) AS P2 ON P1.fk_user_from = P2.fk_user_from AND P1' at line 6

Comment: `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` where shuffled, I've corrected that, maybe try again now. The code is untested of course as I can't access your database..